# Virtualbox - this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 64-bit

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu server on a Virtualbox machine. Every time I attempt to install I get the following:

```
this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detects an i686 CPU, unable to boot
```

I'm running virtualbox on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (64 bit). I've been able to successfully run Arch Linux (64 bit) just fine on the same virtualbox install.

These are the settings I have for VM:

- Enable VT-x/AMD-V is checked

[image]

[image]

Comment: The arch iso is a dual iso, as in the one ISO file has the i386 and AMD64. Try using the 32 bit iso, I can guarantee you'll get Ubuntu running

Comment: @jbuch14 That will work for getting a machine up and running. Though I would like to figure out why it isn't working with 64 bit considering I am using a 64 bit processor with virtualization enabled in my BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will update it if need. but I have no virtualbox around here to make a step by step

Do you have a PENTIUM 4? if less then is weird you have successfully running your 64 bits archlinux .

I think you should at least do this :

1. Try a creating a new VM
2. Enable VT-x/AMD-V or similar at your bios too
3. Have a 64 bits host ( archlinux proves you already have it :c )
4. Give at least two cores to your ubuntu server 64bits VM

Comment: i5-2500k. I'll try throwing two cores at it to see if that makes a difference.

Edit: Same result with 2 cores. =\

Comment: Oddly tried restarting the newly created VM and it worked with the 64bit iso. Not sure what the issue was, but thanks for the help.

Comment: lol, good to know... just in case of some one reading comments: something similar happened to me at windows. I dind't chose a 64 bits version when creating a new VM (this only pre-configure for you) but meabie do something else our particular hw specs

Comment: What worked for me is to recreate the VM. I had VT-x disabled when I created the VM. When I restarted the computer, it still wasn't working so I assume that VirtualBox kept the bad config around.

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to BIOS and check whether VT-x (Virtualization Technology) is enabled.
Use Del key or F2 key when booting your PC. Then go to Advanced --> Processor Configuration --> Intel(R) Virtualization Technology and enable VT.
Press F10 and save configuration and reboot PC.

Now check Virtualbox.

Thanks

Comment: I do have that enabled in my BIOS. One of the first things I did once I built the server.